# Python: How get second columns in unbalanced multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas

```
lists=may['barrier']
lists
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
column(lists,0)
barr_col=column(lists,0)
barr_col
```

Then it gives the first columns data.

But

```
lists=may['barrier']
lists
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
column(lists,0)
barr_col=column(lists,1)
barr_col
```

then there is an error, because lists are not balanced.

How I solve this problem?

Comment: First, start to use sentences, at least if you are asking. Second, paste the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

try defining `column` like this:

```
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] if i < len(row) else None for row in matrix]
```

The way you currently have it defined, I'd expect it to fail whenever i exceeds the length of the `row` in that iteration.  Get around that by testing for it in the list comprehension.